# find date range containing today mysql join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 tables, restaurants and orders, each restaurant has many orders

```
restaurants table
id
name


orders table
id
restaurant_id
date
status
```

if for some date there is no order - it means there is no row in orders table. If there is an order, its status can be 0, 1 or 2. Each row in orders table represents one day.

I need to find those restaurants that, say between `2013-08-15` and `2013-08-25`(that includes current day - `2013-08-19` ) do not have orders at all (which means there is no appropriate row in orders table), or have order status 0 or 1, but along with these conditions the order for today should have status - 2. So, if some restaurant do not have order for today or its status is not 2 - this restaurant should not be listed in the result, but if the order for today exists and its status is 2 the result should contain that restaurant with all the orders list for the above-mentioned date range.

By this query I get the result without the part of today's condition.

```
SELECT r.`id`, r.`name`
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN orders o ON r.id = o.restaurant_id AND o.date between '2013-08-15' AND '2013-08-25'
where o.id is null OR o.`status` = 0 OR o.status = 1
```

How can I add that condition as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do the queries separately and take the union of the results.
Exclude today from the query you have, add a separate query for today.
Something like:

`SELECT r.id, r.name
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN orders o
     ON r.id = o.restaurant_id
     AND o.date between '2013-08-15' AND '2013-08-25'
     AND o.date <> '2013-08-19' -- current day
where o.id is null OR o.status = 0 OR o.status = 1
UNION
SELECT r.id, r.name
FROM restaurants r
INNER JOIN orders o
     ON r.id = o.restaurant_id
     AND o.date = '2013-08-19' -- current day
where o.status = 2`